# How do I modify djoser account verification system

Tags: django, djoser

Here's my custom user model:

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):

    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_verif = models.BooleanField(default=)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["firstname", "lastname"]

    objects = AccountManager()

    def __str__(self):

        return self.email
    
    @property
    def is_staff(self):

        return self.is_superuser

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        
        return self.is_superuser


    def has_perm(*args, **kwargs):

        return True

    def has_module_perms(*args, **kwargs):

        return True
```

So right now I have a standard djoser account verification system. So I'm unable to login with unverified user because the `is_active` field is set to `False`.

Where and how do I modify the code so that every time I verify an account it checks the `is_verif` field instead of the `is_active` and the `is_active` field is always set to True ?

Thank you

Comment: ``is_active`` field is responsible for user to log in your site you should never set it to false if you want to log in your user into your site if you want to change functinality you have create a custom authentication back end for it read more about ``is_active`` flag https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_active

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the is_active field with a methods named is_active with the @property decorator and inside that method return the is_verif value.

```
@property
def is_active(self):
   return self.is_verif
```

But this solution works only if you don't need the is_active field.